# How to trigger a python script on receiving email on outlook with a specific subject?

Tags: python, outlook, triggers, eventtrigger

I have created a python script where I search the inbox for a mail with a specific subject.

As soon as the mail is found , my script reads the body, extracts the information and uses it to create an output response table and send mail to the sender with the response.

This entire process is on demand and I do not want to run my script 24x7 to keep on reading the inbox and check if any email with the subject has arrived.

Are there ways through which I can create a trigger so that whenever I receive an email with that subject in my inbox, the python script gets executed and does all the external work as per the code.

What are the different solutions that can be implemented to achieve the desired results.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Outlook are you using? [Office 365 Outlook have built in "Trigger" & "Event" function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/email-overview)

I don't use Outlook so I don't know how it would call your script, but you could attach to "When new email arrive" trigger.

Comment: Thanks, I may found a solution using this. I am creating a trigger with a specific subject line and in the action using the http connector calling a get request. Then my rest API can trigger the python script and perform the required action.

Comment: @GavyaMehta can you share more information, how you did that. I am looking for similar thing where i wanted to look for message in my outlook email which will then trigger a event to submit the response back to linux server to perform next set of actions

Comment: I used power automate @Sushil.R. I created a custom flow with selecting a when email arrives trigger with a http request which sends the information through my api using which I run my python script. The http connector is a premium service which needs a paid subscription. You can create your own flows here by joining different connectors - https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: Although now I'm using a cron scheduler to run my script every 5 minutes and if an email with a specific subject,etc arrives, my script takes the appropriate action and sends a reply to the email.

Comment: @GavyaMehta thank you for inputs, how your scripts are reading the outlook emails subjects or email body. I am looking something similar to achieve.

where i want to read email body for a keyword "Approved" and once its got it, an event should generate to run a script on Linux machine to execute next steps of actions.

can you guide what what would be next possibles steps ?